# Условие ввода пустой строки в си

Tags: c, строки, циклы, условия

Если пользователь вводит пустую строку name цикл должен прерваться.

```
void Put_txt(void){
FILE *f;
f = fopen("table.txt", "wt");
char name[255];
int num;
int value;
while(name == /*???*/){
scanf("%s",name);
scanf("%d", &num);
scanf("%d", &value);
fprintf(f,"%s", name);
fprintf(f,"\t%d",num);
fprintf(f,"\t%d\n",value);
}
fclose(f);
```

}

Comment: Вводит где? К вас проверка содержимого строки делается до того, как кто-то в нее что-то успевает ввести.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Вводит" где и как? Во-первых, у вас делается проверка вообще не инициализированной строки. Во-вторых, функция `scanf`, которая у вас используется далее, в принципе не позволяет "ввести пустую строку". Функции форматированного ввода группы `scanf` в стандартной библиотеке языка С либо читают *непустую* последовательность данных, либо завершаются с ошибкой, не читая вообще ничего.

Если вы хотите дать пользователю возможность "вводить пустую строку", пользуйтесь функцией `fgets` и проверяйте результат на равенство строке `"\n"`

```
do 
{
  char name[255];
  if (fgets(name, sizeof name, stdin) == NULL)
    break;
  if (strcmp(name, "\n") == 0)
    break;
  ...
} while (1);
```

Имейте только к ввиду, что смешение форматированного и неформатированного ввода имеет свои особенности. Ваши `scanf` будут оставлять во входном буфере символы перевода строки, которые вышеприведенный `fgets` будет воспринимать, как "ввод пустой строки", и приводить к завершению цикла. Между `scanf` и `fgets` буфер ввода надо чистить. А лучше не смешивать форматированный и неформатированный ввод вообще.

Comment: fgets вроде используется для считывания из файла, а мне нужно считывать строку из консоли

Comment: @Orizz: Не из "файла", а из *потока*. Консоль в С - это поток `stdin`.

Answer (score 0):

Может быть

```
while(strlen(name) == 0)
```